# Remove done button in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there a possibility to remove the DONE button from the MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen interface?

Thank You, 
Suse

Comment: could be outdated, but here's my solution http://gavrix.wordpress.com/2012/11/11/injecting-custom-behaviour-in-private-api/

Answer (score 0):

No - the only way to get rid of that button is to use an entire custom interface.